# MimeKit Performance Question about MimeMessage.Load

Tags: c#, mimekit

I'm currently working on implementing support in printing for larger MIME files, from a 50MB threshold to 2000MB and i was doing some performance tests, and i noticed the MimeMessage.Load(stream) (this is the [Load(Stream, CancellationToken)](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/M_MimeKit_MimeMessage_Load_4.htm) method) is having a filling my RAM memory really fast, and for some platforms the printer will run on, this will crash it.

Right now i am feeding to my Load method a NetworkStream and I read that using [Load(Stream, Boolean, CancellationToken)](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/M_MimeKit_MimeMessage_Load_3.htm) could help me with my performance issue.

Did anyone experienced the same and can maybe explain how does Load with persistent work and how i can avoid using too much memory?

Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

The `Load(Stream stream, bool persistent, CancellationToken cancellationToken)` method will avoid loading the *content* of each message into RAM *unless* the stream is not seekable.

`NetworkStream` is not seekable.

If you are going to be loading messages that are 2GB in size, you need to copy the contents from the `NetworkStream` to a `FileStream` and *then* load the message using `persistent: true`.

In MimeKit, the `persistent` argument is telling the `MimeParser` that the stream will continue to exist and be readable *after* the parser has finished parsing the message. When the `MimeParser` is told this, instead of loading the contents of the message into memory, it instead keeps track of the stream offsets and creates a proxy `Stream` object that can be used to read the content between the beginning and ending stream offsets of the original stream at a later point in time and sets *that* on the `MimeMessage` rather than a `MemoryStream`.

Comment: only 1 more question, after i copy the content from my network stream to a file stream, do i have to feed to MimeMessage.Load the file path as a string or it is supposed to work with the FileStream obejct aswell?

Comment: You can use the FileStream

Comment: This is what I tried, but for some reason I get a FormatException while loading. What i am doing is to create a FileStream and then to copy the content from my inputStream using CopyTo. I dont know yet why it is failing. Could it be because the FileStream is not closed?

Comment: Did you set the position of the FileStream back to 0? No one seems to remember to do that.